How to bypass login to use campus network?
When I connect to the campus network, a login page pops up. If I don't have a username and password, is there any way I can use the campus network?
I can't fulfill this need myself, and I hope someone can help me. Please, I'm really desperate to know the answer.

i think you're on the wrong forum. this is not the dark web :)

Simply, The answer is, You cannot do that.
It's because without authenticating yourself, the firewall will not allow you to access the network.
You would obviously need credentials from network administrator or there would be general credentials in your campus for guests. You can use that too.
